# Querying to Oracle using .NET MVC

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller

I have been following some MVC tutorials that connect to a sql mdf database and was wondering if there were any tutuorials that existed out there that show you how to create a data model using an Oracle database. The company I work for uses Oracle on the back end so getting MVC to tie into Oracle as the Model would help me greatly. Thanks.

By the way, I want to try and create the database connection without using a 3rd party tool such as DevArt's dotConnect or OraDeveloper's tools but if that is the only way, I would like to hear how to make it work with this tool.

Edit: .NET Specific MVC Thanks @Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about .NET MVC here, MVC itself really has nothing "built in" for data access.  You would just use whatever .NET data access method you feel is appropriate for your app (ADO.NET, NHibernate, LINQ, etc..).

So, you might want to check out these questions to start with:

[Which is the “best” data access framework/approach for C# and .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657220/which-is-the-best-data-access-framework-approach-for-c-and-net)

[Using linq with oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790/is-there-a-way-to-use-linq-to-oracle)

[What would be the most convenient way to connect Visual Studio 2005 (C#) to Oracle8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230927/what-would-be-the-most-convenient-way-to-connect-visual-studio-2005-c-to-oracl)

I'm sure you can find a lot more if you search this site for ".net and oracle" or something similar.